# Is this set is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

**Question**: $A= \{x∈\mathbb{R}: \tan{x}\text{ is not differentiable}\}$ is complete?

**My attempt**: clearly $A=\{(2n+1)\frac{π}{2}: n∈\mathbb{Z}\}$.

I can see each entry of $A$ is irrational, and we know between two irrational there exists rational number(hence infinity of rationals!) which is limit point of $A$ but does not belongs to $A$. Hence $A$ is not closed! But, $A$ subset of complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$, so is that imply $A$ is Not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument about there being a rational between any two (distinct) irrationals doesn't really make a lot of sense, in that this fact doesn't show that such rational numbers are limit points of $A$ (they're not).

You know that a subspace of a complete metric space is also complete if and only if it is closed. Indeed, $A$ is closed; its complement is a union of open sets $\left((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2},(2n+3)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and hence open.

Another way of thinking about it is that $A$ is *uniformly discrete*, which is to say that there is a fixed $\delta>0$ such that the distance between any two distinct elements of $A$ is $\geq \delta$. In general, if a metric space is uniformly discrete, it will be complete, as the given metric will be strongly equivalent to the standard discrete metric, and discrete metric spaces are complete (Cauchy sequences in such space must be eventually constant so convergent).

Comment: Sir, isn't there is result that, "subset $A$ of "complete metric space" $X$ is itself complete if and only if it $A$ is closed set in $X$?

Comment: $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sir, please can you show $A$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$ please

Comment: The complement of $A$ is a union of open intervals, hence open. I've edited my answer to go the route you're thinking of

Comment: Sir, though I get the other way! But really unable to see, how you find that, complement of $A$? and how you see it's complement is union of open sets..:-(

Comment: You know that $A = \{ (2n+1) \frac{\pi}{2} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I claim that $A^\mathsf{c} = B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left( (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}, (2n+3)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. This is immediate by seeing that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (no element of $A$ appears in $B$ by construction) and their union is $\mathbb{R}$ (any element not in $A$ will still have to be between two consecutive elements in $A$, i.e. in $B$). $B$ is clearly a union of open intervals, and unions of open sets are open.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for giving your valuable time, got it..:-)